# Polymorphic Associations or something easier

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-key-relationship, polymorphic-associations

This is my first post and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere....

I have a database that has multiple companies,each company has multiple locations.
I'm running into problems trying to define the contacts. Some contacts need to be global and available
at any location....some contacts only need to exist for one location. In the contact_info table below 
we specify the visibility of the contact (company or location). However the location needs to choose its primary contact.
That leaves a FK from contact -> location and from location -> contact.

I know there is another table involved but I can't seem to conceptualize it.

```
CREATE TABLE `company_info` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`));

CREATE TABLE `location_info` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`company_info` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
`name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`primary_contact_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
UNIQUE KEY(`company_id`,`name`),
FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company_info(id)
FOREIGN KEY (primary_contact_id) REFERENCES contact_info(id));

CREATE TABLE `contact_info` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`company_id` INT
`location_id` INT,
`type` ENUM('Company','Location') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Company',
`first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`last_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
UNIQUE KEY(`id`,`company_id`,`location_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES location_info(id),
FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company_info(id)
```

Comment: You said that some contacts exist at multiple locations and some exist at one location.
Is that dependent on which companies the contacts are a part of?
E.g. If a company has a few locations, then all the contacts that are employed by that company have those same locations. And if the company has one location, then the contact will have that one location.

Comment: Company "Ajax" has contact "Mike" who should be the primary contact for Locations "New York", "Los Angeles" and "Miami".....They have a contact "Joe" who should only appear in "New York"...In the contact_info table Mike would have company_id = ajax, location_id NULL while Joe would have a company_id NULL and location_id = New York....When I mean "appear" there is a form where you choose the primary contact for the location

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way would be splitting it up so that there's a table for your companies, a table with your users, and a table solely for the purpose of storing all connections (i.e. `EntryID, UserID, CompanyID`). This way you'll be able to easily load them afterwards.